# how to forward declare a template class like template function in the same main file

Tags: c++, templates

I want to forward declare a template class like template  function in the same main file. But I got an error that my class has incomplete type and can't not be defined.
Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T> class Foo;

int main()
{
    Foo<int> ok;
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

template <class T>
class Foo
{
private:
    int test;
public:
    Foo() {test = 1;}
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <class T> class Foo;
```

This is a good start. This is a perfect forward declaration.

```
Foo<int> ok;
```

Unfortunately, at this point the compiler needs to know what the template class actually is. A forward declaration is no longer sufficient. The compiler has no idea, at this point, even how big this class is, so how can it create an object whose size it doesn't know?

A forward declaration is sufficient for declaring a pointer or a reference to a class instance (it doesn't matter if it's regular class or a template). You don't need to know how big a class is for declaring a pointer or a reference to it. You also don't need to know how big a class is for a few other things also, but a forward declaration is not sufficient for declaring an instance of the class itself. The class must be defined, at this point.

This has nothing to do with template classes. This is true for all classes, template and regular classes.

Comment: I want to know more about the differences between declaring a function and what I tried to do(in this question).

Comment: What you tried to do in this question has nothing to do with declaring any function.